# How to position a font-awesome icon behind a scrolling table header?

Tags: javascript, html, css, font-awesome

I have the following table:

```
<div id="table-container>
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <td>
                ...
                </td>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <fa-stack>
                        <!-- some stacked icons -->
                    </fa-stack>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
        <!-- more tbody items -->
    </table>
</div>
```

I am using javascript to fixate the table header when scrolling:

```
document.getElementById('table-container').addEventListener('scroll', function (): void {
    let translate = 'translate(0,' + this.scrollTop + 'px)';
    this.querySelector('thead').style.transform = translate;
});
```

My problem is, that the stacked font-awesome icons appear before the table header. Trying to hide them behind it using z-index doesn't work.

When I remove the position:absolute/position:relative attributes from the font-awesome classes, the icons disappear behind the header. But then they aren't stacked anymore. Any suggestions?

Here's a codepen that shows the problem: https://codepen.io/ahouben/pen/jaZbvm

Comment: Try adding a `position: relative` to your `td`s.

Comment: It may depend on where you are trying to declare the `z-index` properties. Does `thead` have a higher `z-index` than `tbody`?

Comment: @jcaron: Did that, doesn't help :/

Comment: @UncaughtTypeError I set the z-index of thead to 10 and the z-index of the fa-stack item to 1. Doesn't do anything. But fiddling with thead and tbody is a good idea. I'll try that.

Edit: Unfortunately it doesn't do anything :/

Comment: Oh, I should probably mention that `z-index` has no affect on elements that are not "positioned" - so is `tbody` positioned `relative`?

Comment: Can you provide a jsFiddle or something equivalent?

Comment: Just did that :-) https://codepen.io/ahouben/pen/jaZbvm

Comment: @UncaughtTypeError: Yes I made sure to position them relative.

Comment: Give the <span class="fa-stack"> a negative z-index(?)

Comment: @VilleKoo Hmm. I tried that in my codepen. There it works. When I try it at my original code, the stack disappears behind the whole table.

Comment: Declaring the following styles on `thead` resolves the issue demonstrated in CodePen the external link points to: `thead {
    display: table-caption;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 9;
}`

Comment: @UncaughtTypeError The display: table-caption does the trick, but messes up the table style. Good tip though. Thanks.

Comment: Could you elaborate? Does it mess up the table style in your production code? I didn't notice any compromised table structure in the CodePen provided, apart from a minor width adjustment in the table cells of the table header - but this is negligible and easily resolved by adjusting affected widths accordingly. Are we playing with a full deck of cards here? I mean is there code in your production that we can't account for in your examples?

Comment: It's code that is used in production. Yes. But I guess I can provide some screenshots:
Here's a screenshot that shows the problem:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/jfrrnwa8tsdngww/Screenshot%202017-11-20%2011.02.03.png?dl=0

Here's a screenshot that shows the table using your solution:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/cbju1bqse487j99/Screenshot%202017-11-20%2011.04.04.png?dl=0

As you can see, the widths of the tbody cells lose their alignment with the thead cells.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I set the z-index on both the thead and th elements, and I find that the thead slides over top of the fontawesome icons.